# Multiple Tab Switch

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

i hope you can help me. I try a tabswitch, but i get some problems. I want to use the code. How i can use more then one tabcontent in the same tablink? For my sample i add a second "Tokyo" ID.(I know that i use 2 same IDs) Now i want to show it as second option under openCity Tokyo.

The second problem is, that at the start i see all tabs without css. But i want only see tab Paris as sample.

I hope you can help me :)

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/dc5p38ed/

```js
openCity = function(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    for(var j=0; j<document.getElementsByClassName(cityName).length; j++){
     document.getElementsByClassName(cityName)[j].style.display = "block";
    }
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent London">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent Paris">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div class="tabcontent Tokyo">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent Tokyo">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thats working fine. But at the beginning, i get all options. But i only want to see the first if the page load.

Comment: @RonNy Here you go with the updated fiddle with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/dc5p38ed/2/

Answer (score 0):

**`id` must be unique**, and if you want multiple same ids then use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like

```
var allIds= document.querySelectorAll('#'+cityName);
allIds[allIds.length-1].style.display = "block"; // for the last id to be shown
```

And to make Paris active add a class `active` to `Paris` and manually trigger click event like,

```
document.querySelector('.tablinks.active').click();
```

**Snippet,**

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  var allIds = document.querySelectorAll('#' + cityName);
  allIds[allIds.length - 1].style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.querySelector('.tablinks.active').click();
```

```html
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan Second.</p>
</div>
```